# How to add a back button in the top corner of the left page?

Tags: css, r, shiny, back-button

I am trying to add a back button to the top-corner of the left page, with a triangular form.

Here is a reproducible example of the Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 5px 0;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the body */
        position: relative; /* Add position relative for the logo */
      }
      .input-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the input container */
        padding: 20px; /* Add padding for better visibility */
      }
      .input-container input[type='text'],
      .input-container input[type='number'],
      .input-container .btn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 5px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        color: navy; /* Text color navy */
      }
      .input-container .btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: white;
      }
      /* Style for Your Details text */
      .details-container {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .details-text {
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .logo {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 300px; /* Adjust the width of the logo */
        height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
        display: none; /* Initially hide the logo */
      }
    "))
  ),
  titlePanel(" "),
  uiOutput("page")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$page <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$currentPage)) {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            actionButton("startButton", "START", style = "font-size: 50px;") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    } else if (input$currentPage == "page2") {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
            textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
            textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
            textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
            textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    } else if (input$currentPage == "page3") {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
            actionButton("basicButton", "Basic"),
            actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate"),
            actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +"),
            actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure"),
            actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src ="www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$startButton, {
    output$page <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
            textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name"),
            textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality"),
            textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age"),
            textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email"),
            actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nextButton, {
    name <- input$name
    nationality <- input$nationality
    age <- input$age
    email <- input$email
    
    output$page <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
            actionButton("basicButton", "Basic", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And this is an example of the the "Back" button I need on each page, but starting with the second page, all the way to the other pages.

[image]

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example for a back button in the corner similar to the one in your screenshot. You can of course edit the `CSS` in order to improve the example.

[image]

Notice that there are several repetitions inside your example which should be avoided. However, I did not refactor your code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 5px 0;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the body */
        position: relative; /* Add position relative for the logo */
      }
      .input-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the input container */
        padding: 20px; /* Add padding for better visibility */
      }
      .input-container input[type='text'],
      .input-container input[type='number'],
      .input-container .btn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 5px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        color: navy; /* Text color navy */
      }
      .input-container .btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: white;
      }
      /* Style for Your Details text */
      .details-container {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .details-text {
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .logo {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 300px; /* Adjust the width of the logo */
        height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
        display: none; /* Initially hide the logo */
      }
      div#corner-triangle {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
        border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0 0 25px 9px #fff;
      }
    "))
    ),
    titlePanel(" "),
    uiOutput("page")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$page <- renderUI({
        if (is.null(input$currentPage)) {
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    actionButton("startButton", "START", style = "font-size: 50px;") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        } 
        
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$startButton, {
        output$page <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
                    textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name"),
                    textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality"),
                    textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age"),
                    textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email"),
                    actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                div(id = "corner-triangle",
                    actionButton(label="Back", inputId = "bck1",
                                 style = "top: -150px; 
                                        left: 25px;
                                        font-size: 25px;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transform: rotate(-45deg);
                                        color: navy;
                                        border: none;
                                        background-color: transparent;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        padding: 2em;
                                        margin: -2em;
                                        outline: none;")),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$nextButton, {
        name <- input$name
        nationality <- input$nationality
        age <- input$age
        email <- input$email
        
        output$page <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
                    actionButton("basicButton", "Basic", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                div(id = "corner-triangle",
                    actionButton(label="Back", inputId = "bck2",
                                 style = "top: -150px; 
                                        left: 25px;
                                        font-size: 25px;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transform: rotate(-45deg);
                                        color: navy;
                                        border: none;
                                        background-color: transparent;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        padding: 2em;
                                        margin: -2em;
                                        outline: none;")),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$bck1, {
        output$page <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                div(
                    class = "input-container",
                    actionButton("startButton", "START", style = "font-size: 50px;") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                tags$img(
                    src = "www/free_english_logo.png",
                    class = "logo",
                    width = "400px"
                ) # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$bck2, {
        output$page <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
                    textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name"),
                    textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality"),
                    textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age"),
                    textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email"),
                    actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                div(id = "corner-triangle",
                    actionButton(label="Back", inputId = "bck1",
                                 style = "top: -150px; 
                                        left: 25px;
                                        font-size: 25px;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transform: rotate(-45deg);
                                        color: navy;
                                        border: none;
                                        background-color: transparent;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        padding: 2em;
                                        margin: -2em;
                                        outline: none;")),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you a lot for answering. I have managed to get it but my logo disappeared . Is this because of the back buttons?

Comment: it worked very nicely! Thanks a lot! also, may I flag another struggle I am facing with another issue at the same app , here it is:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77526250/how-to-adjust-the-sizes-of-the-boxes-and-spaces-between-them-with-rshiny ; do you mind helping please?

Comment: You are welcome. I already had a look at it and may write an answer later, but it can take some time. Maybe within the next couple of days, if nobody else does.