# How to adjust the sizes of the boxes and spaces between them?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have issues with the sizes of the boxes within my Shiny app and  I also have some issues with spaces as well.

Here is a reproducible shiny code:

```
    library(shiny)

# Define the logo URL


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 5px 0;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the body */
        position: relative; /* Add position relative for the logo */
      }
      .input-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the input container */
        padding: 20px; /* Add padding for better visibility */
      }
      .input-container input[type='text'],
      .input-container input[type='number'],
      .input-container .btn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 5px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        color: navy; /* Text color navy */
      }
      .input-container .btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: white;
      }
      /* Style for Your Details text */
      .details-container {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .details-text {
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .logo {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 300px; /* Adjust the width of the logo */
        height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
        display: none; /* Initially hide the logo */
      }
    "))
  ),
  titlePanel(" "),
  uiOutput("page")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$page <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$currentPage)) {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            actionButton("startButton", "START", style = "font-size: 50px;") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    } else if (input$currentPage == "page2") {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
            textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
            textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
            textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
            textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    } else if (input$currentPage == "page3") {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
            actionButton("basicButton", "Basic"),
            actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate"),
            actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +"),
            actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure"),
            actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src ="www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$startButton, {
    output$page <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
            textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name"),
            textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality"),
            textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age"),
            textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email"),
            actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nextButton, {
    name <- input$name
    nationality <- input$nationality
    age <- input$age
    email <- input$email
    
    output$page <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
            actionButton("basicButton", "Basic", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now if you run the code above in R this is what you'll get:

[image]

But I want:

1. a bit more space yet equal space between the first 4 boxes
2. and want them longer like the second page
3. the NEXT button should be shorter and lower than all four boxes.

Here is an example of how I want my boxes:

1st pict:

[image]

2nd pict - that shows the how long I want the boxes, the same as the second page boxes:

[image]

Now with the second page, I have similar issues :

1. with the space in between the boxes - first three boxes "Begginer" , "Intermediate" and "Intermidiate+" to have the same space (but want a bit wider than as it is now). And the last button to be equal distance between "Not sure?"

This is what I have now

[image]

And I want it like this:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve these sizes and spaces with shiny app or even css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example which should be similar to the one as given in your provided screenshots. I commented the relevant `css` parts, you can edit them for increasing or decreasing the `margin` and `width` of the input-containers and buttons.

[image]

[image]

```
library(shiny)

# Define the logo URL


ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 5px 0;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the body */
        position: relative; /* Add position relative for the logo */
      }
      .input-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the input container */
        padding: 20px; /* Add padding for better visibility */
        width: 600px; /* larger inputs as desired */
      }
      .input-container input[type='text'],
      .input-container input[type='number'],
      .input-container .btn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 15px 0;  /* increased from 5 to 15 for more space */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        color: navy; /* Text color navy */
      }
      .input-container .btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: white;
      }
      /* Style for Your Details text */
      .details-container {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .details-text {
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .logo {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 300px; /* Adjust the width of the logo */
        height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
        display: none; /* Initially hide the logo */
      }
      .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 50px; /* larger space to next element */
      }
      .shiny-input-container:not(.shiny-input-container-inline) {
        width: 600px;   /* larger inputs as desired */
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      #nextButton, #nextButtonPage3 {
        width: 200px;   /* shorter than the other buttons */
        background-color: green; /* like in the screenshot */
        margin-top: 60px; /* larger space to above */
      }
      #notSureButton {
        margin-top: 60px;   /* larger space to above */
      } 
      #startButton {
        width: 300px; /* width of the start button, separately defined */
      }
    "))
    ),
    titlePanel(" "),
    uiOutput("page")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$page <- renderUI({
        if (is.null(input$currentPage)) {
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    actionButton("startButton", "START", style = "font-size: 50px;") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        } else if (input$currentPage == "page2") {
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
                    textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
                    textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
                    textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
                    textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        } else if (input$currentPage == "page3") {
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
                    actionButton("basicButton", "Basic"),
                    actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate"),
                    actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +"),
                    actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure"),
                    actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                tags$img(src ="www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$startButton, {
        output$page <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    tags$p(class = "details-text", "Your Details:"),
                    textInput("name", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name"),
                    textInput("nationality", label = NULL, placeholder = "Nationality"),
                    textInput("age", label = NULL, value = "", placeholder = "Age"),
                    textInput("email", label = NULL, placeholder = "Email"),
                    actionButton("nextButton", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$nextButton, {
        name <- input$name
        nationality <- input$nationality
        age <- input$age
        email <- input$email
        
        output$page <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                div(class = "input-container",
                    tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
                    actionButton("basicButton", "Basic", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
                    actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "NEXT") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
                ),
                tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
            )
        })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```