# why do I not get the page with circles into my shiny app?

Tags: android, r, shiny, golem

I am trying to build a shiny app application, within R/Rstudio.

this is the code I am trying, which is part of the bigger code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 5px 0;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the body */
      }
      .circle-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .circle {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: lightblue; /* Use the same blue color */
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .circle img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    "))
  ),
  div(class = "circle-container", id = "circles")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$circles <- renderUI({
    circle_ui_list <- lapply(1:8, function(index) {
      image_path <- paste0("www/teacher", index, ".png")
      div(
        id = paste0("circle_", index),
        class = "circle",
        img(src = image_path, width = 80, height = 80)
      )
    })
    tagList(circle_ui_list)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want this page to look like 4th page, where I will have each teacher into those circles.

this is how it looks like: [image]

this page is part of a other pages, this is the code repository: https://github.com/gabrielburcea/fec.git

and want to integrate the page I am attempting to create within other pages.
for more details check this page -  [How to adjust the sizes of the boxes and spaces between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77526250/how-to-adjust-the-sizes-of-the-boxes-and-spaces-between-them)

but the wider reproducible code only for first page and third page is this:

```
library(shiny)

# Define the logo URL


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 5px 0;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the body */
        position: relative; /* Add position relative for the logo */
      }
      .input-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: navy; /* Set background color for the input container */
        padding: 20px; /* Add padding for better visibility */
        width: 600px; /* Adjust the width of the input container */
      }
      .input-container input[type='text'],
      .input-container input[type='number'],
      .input-container .btn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 15px 0; /*increased from 5 to 15 for more space between inputs */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        color: navy; /* Text color navy */
        margin-bottom: 50px; /* larger space to next element */
      }
      .input-container .btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: white;
      }
      /* Style for Your Details text */
      .details-container {
        text-align: center;
        width: 600px; /*larger inputs as desired */
        width: 100%;
      }
      .details-text {
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      ,form-group {
      margin-bottom: 50px; /* larger space to next element */
      }
      .shiny-input-container:not(.shiny-input-container-inline) {
      width: 600px; /*larger inputs as desired */
      max-width: 100%;
      }
      #nextButton, #nextButtonPage3 {
        width: 300px;   /* shorter than the other buttons */
        background-color: green; /* like in the screenshot */
        margin-top: 60px; /* larger space to above */
      }
      #notSureButton {
       width: 295px;   /* shorter than the other buttons */
       margin-top: 60px;   /* larger space to above */
      }
      #startButton {
        width: 300px; /* width of the start button, separately defined */
      }
       div#corner-triangle {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
        border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0 0 25px 9px #fff;
       }
      .logo {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 1px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 300px; /* Adjust the width of the logo */
        height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
      }
    "))
  ),
  titlePanel(" "),
  uiOutput("page")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$page <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$currentPage)) {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            actionButton("startButton", "Start", style = "font-size: 35px; color: navy;") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px") # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    } else if (input$currentPage == "page2") {
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
            actionButton("basicButton", "Basic"),
            actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate"),
            actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +"),
            actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure"),
            actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "Next", style = "font-size: 30px; color: navy;") #  style = "font-size: 24px;"
        ),
        div(id = "corner-triangle",
            actionButton(label="Back", inputId = "bck2",
                         style = "top: -150px;
                                        left: 25px;
                                        font-size: 25px;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transform: rotate(-45deg);
                                        color: navy;
                                        border: none;
                                        background-color: transparent;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        padding: 2em;
                                        margin: -2em;
                                        outline: none;")),
        tags$img(src ="www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px")
      )
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$startButton, {
    output$page <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
            actionButton("basicButton", "Basic", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "Next", style = "font-size: 30px; color: navy;") #
        ),
        div(id = "corner-triangle",
            actionButton(label="Back", inputId = "bck2",
                         style = "top: -150px;
                                        left: 25px;
                                        font-size: 25px;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transform: rotate(-45deg);
                                        color: navy;
                                        border: none;
                                        background-color: transparent;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        padding: 2em;
                                        margin: -2em;
                                        outline: none;")),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px")
      )
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$bck1, {
    output$page <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        div(
          class = "input-container",
          actionButton("startButton", "Start", style = "font-size: 35px; color: navy;")
        ),
        tags$img(
          src = "www/free_english_logo.png",
          class = "logo",
          width = "400px"
        ) # Adjust the width of the logo
      )
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$bck2, {
    output$page <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        div(class = "input-container",
            tags$p(class = "details-text", "Teaching level:"),
            actionButton("basicButton", "Basic", style = "background-color: lightblue; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediateButton", "Intermediate", style = "background-color: lightyellow; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("intermediatePlusButton", "Intermediate +", style = "background-color: lightgreen; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("notSureButton", "Not sure", style = "background-color: lightgray; color: navy;"),
            actionButton("nextButtonPage3", "Next", style = "font-size: 30px; color: navy;") #
        ),
        div(id = "corner-triangle",
            actionButton(label="Back", inputId = "bck2",
                         style = "top: -150px;
                                        left: 25px;
                                        font-size: 25px;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transform: rotate(-45deg);
                                        color: navy;
                                        border: none;
                                        background-color: transparent;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        padding: 2em;
                                        margin: -2em;
                                        outline: none;")),
        tags$img(src = "www/free_english_logo.png", class = "logo", width = "400px")
      )
    })
  })# Adjust the width of the logo
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

it would be helpful if I can integrate the first code with the other pages code

Comment: Are you missing `uiOutput("circles")` on the `ui` side?

Comment: @YBS I have re-edited the post and added a reproducible code , is there a chance you can help me with how to integrate the page within the other pages with the code?

Comment: You are checking for `input$currentPage`, but have not defined "currentPage".  Please consider defining it. Also, using outputs inside observer is not necessary.  You can make it a reactive object and define output$page only once.  Lastly, perhaps you should consider using Shinydashboard, navbarpage or other ways to view multiple pages.

Comment: @YBS is there a chance you can post an answer then?